# How to write a test case for a function where there is a if condition using jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I have a onUpdate function like bellow

```
onUpdate = data => {
    if (parseInt(data.quantity) < 1) {
        this.props.setErrorPopUp({
            message: 'You cannot set quantity to zero.Use delete actions',
            action: 'danger',
            time: '5000'
        })
    } else {
        this.props.formSubmitAttempt({
            product: data.id,
            quantity: data.quantity
        })
    }
}
```

I want to write a test using jest to test both of the scenarios .
As i am new to jest how can i test this scenario
Thanks

Comment: did you try anything?

Comment: not at all for this , i have try some basic examples in tutorials

Comment: i have no idea to how to test the if condition

Comment: you need to write 2 unit test for it. one with passing argument which goes through if path and second with which goes to else path. i have given example in my answer

Answer (score 1):

You could use instance to get onUpdate function and pass setErrorPopup and formSubmitAttempt as mocks.

```
const props = {
    setErrorPopUp: jest.fn();
    formSubmitAttempt: jest.fn();

}
const wrapper = shallow(<Component {...props} />
wrapper.instance().onUpdate({ quantity: 0});
expect(props.setErrorPopUp).toHaveBeenCalled();

wrapper.instance().onUpdate({ quantity: 3 });
expect(props.formSubmitAttempt).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Comment: setErrorPopup and formSubmitAttempt are redux action

Comment: so should i have to follow this  https://alligator.io/react/testing-redux-actions/

Comment: You don't need to worry about it. They are just props for your component.

Comment: is instance() method come from enzyme just as shallow

Comment: yes. it gives you access to all methods in your component.
https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/instance.html